# Customization for one view controller effecting the orientation for another viewcontroller in ios 8.1

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

ManagerNavVC.m  is Navigationcontroller class

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
 if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[AriticalDis class]]) {

     return YES;
 }
return NO;
  }
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

  if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[AriticalDis class]]) {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

   }

  else if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]]) {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }

     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }
```

Here the problem is I am writing code to handle only `ArticalDis` class will supports Orientations for both landScape and Portrait but from here pushing `ArticalDis` class to `Settingsview` class it should only support to portrait only but it automatically changing the view to landscape even when I mentioned the view should be in portrait mode.